# A regex string to match both Integers and Double in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this that is read from a file

```
string line = rows=1500,cols=1500,res=0.1,tl_y=75,tl_x=-75,br_y=-75,br_x=75
```

and a regex match code is this

```
string pattern = @"rows=(\d+),cols=(\d+),res=(\d+\.\d+),tl_y=(-?\d+\.\d+),tl_x=(-?\d+\.\d+),br_y=(-?\d+\.\d+),br_x=(-?\d+\.\d+)";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, pattern);
```

This doesn't work when the tl_pt and br_pt X and Y values are integers.
It only works when they are doubles

I cannot fix this simply by changing `75` to `75.0`

I need the appropriate pattern to match either integer without the `.` or double with the `.`

Comment: Use `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to match both integers and double values.

Comment: Do you really need to use regex here? A combination of `Split()` and `ToDictionary` would work as well.